# How to run mobile joomla on desktop browser?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6

I need to see the output by mobile joomla plugin in my regular browser, to be able to style and tweak things easily. 
In older versions of mobile joomla ther was an option ('Mobile Always') that would output mobile views all the time. But I can't find it current version (1.0.3)

Answer (score 0):

You can always install [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) for Firefox. It gives you the ability to change to a mobile user agent and also a few others things such as IE6 and IE7. You can also add others. Hope this helps. Regards.

Comment: well I did that. I use chrome (v22) and it has pretty advanced user agent features. but the site still responds with the view that I usually see. the site displays with mobile tempate only on my iPhone.